# How to count which decade is best represented on the list?

Tags: mysql

I need your help. I am now stuck in my school project. I had to create a database and complete the tasks. One of the task was "Find out, Which decade is best represented on the list?" I have no idea how to do that. Please look at picture and tell me if it is even possible and how?

[My Database preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU1NR.jpg)

[image]

Comment: just click on My Database and you will see my database

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it**.* If you can't get started at all, ask your instructor for help.

Comment: Look up `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(*)`.  This should help you find the Year that's most represented.  Then use something like `year / 10` instead, to do the sane thing by decade...

Comment: If I understood right, some of you guys are worried of copy-pasting and of "expecting other people to do their job". So, there is just school project. I dont know why knowladge which I got during the course is not enough for completing this task but this isn't about "expecting other people to do this". I would do it by myself but I have no idea how. So, if some of you are afraid that I just copypaste the solution or if you consider your information so valuable that you dont want to share it, why dont you just skip this post instead of telling here how wrong it is to ask people for solution?

Comment: @Olli Don't worry about that, just keep in mind that Q&A format here have some rules. People here provide help for actual code (some sample and brief explanation what you have done so far are required) and your question really looks like "do it for me". You can always edit your question to provide more info. Meanwhile, look at my answer bellow and feel free to ask if something is hard to understand or not understandable at all. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score -2):

To understand how to calculate decade and apply that value to query you have to understand how counting rows works in SQL. I'll try to turn this answer into step-by-step guide in order to help you learning. You haven't mentioned your current level of knowledge on this subject so I'll explain my answer from the very beginning.

---

### Basic concept (counting movies by year)

Your **movies** table (I'll use that name for your table) doesn't have decades stored so you need to calculate that value from **year** column. To count rows we use [COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) function which basically counts rows by some criteria. Simple usage of COUNT() function would be

```
 SELECT
   COUNT(*)
 FROM `movies`;
```

This query will return number of all rows in your table.

When we want to specify criteria for counting we use [GROUP BY clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). To count all movies published in specific year we need query like this

```
 SELECT
   `year`,
   COUNT(*) AS 'count'
 FROM `movies`
 GROUP BY `year`;
```

This query will count all rows where the **year** column have same value. Now we're selecting two columns, one for **year** and one to contain number of rows for that year (i called it **'count'**). We use **AS** keyword to rename column name when needed which I did for COUNT(*). Our result now has **year** column containing each year from your table once, followed by number of rows for that year (reflected in **count** column).

This is basic structure we need.

---

### Calculating decades

What actually is your goal is grouping number of rows by multiple years. If you had **decade** column in the table job could be simply done by using

```
 GROUP BY `decade`
```

but you don't have it so we need to find a workaround to calculate it at run-time.

Each decade represents range of 10 years. Decade 1 starts at zero year, decade 2 at year 10, decade 200 at year 1990, etc. We need to get proper decade for each year from table and later GROUP BY result by that value.

To get decade where each year belongs to, we need to do some math in SQL.

```
 FLOOR (`year`/10) + 1
```

Function [FLOOR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) will keep integer part of the argument only (this is true only when argument is equal or greater than 0, which is your case). So when we divide year 1995 with 10 we get 199.5 and FLOOR() simply cuts off .5 from the value returning integer part only - 199. Because of years in range between 1990 and 1999 belong to 200th decade we increment that value with 1 to get right decade.

To demonstrate how decade value is calculated from year using formula above take a look of this sample.

```
 +------+---------+---------------+--------+
 | year | year/10 | after FLOOR() | decade |
 +------+---------+---------------+--------+
 | 1988 |   198.8 |           198 |    199 |
 +------+---------+---------------+--------+
 | 1989 |   198.9 |           198 |    199 |
 +------+---------+---------------+--------+
 | 1990 |     199 |           199 |    200 |
 +------+---------+---------------+--------+
 | 1991 |   199.1 |           199 |    200 |
 +------+---------+---------------+--------+
 | 1992 |   199.2 |           199 |    200 |
 +------+---------+---------------+--------+
             [... 1993-1997 ...]
 +------+---------+---------------+--------+
 | 1998 |   199.8 |           199 |    200 |
 +------+---------+---------------+--------+
 | 1999 |   199.9 |           199 |    200 |
 +------+---------+---------------+--------+
 | 2000 |     200 |           200 |    201 |
 +------+---------+---------------+--------+
 | 2001 |   200.1 |           200 |    201 |
 +------+---------+---------------+--------+
```

With right decade calculated we can now easily write a query which will return number of rows where criteria for grouping is **decade** instead of **single year**.

```
 SELECT
   FLOOR (`year`/10)+1 AS 'decade',
   COUNT(*) AS 'count'
 FROM `movies`
 GROUP BY `decade`;
```

Course, we need our result to be sorted from the greatest value down by **count** column, in order to get "the best decade". Adding [ORDER BY clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html) at the end of query will do the trick.

Complete query now will look like this.

```
 SELECT
   FLOOR (`year`/10)+1 AS 'decade',
   COUNT(*) AS 'count'
 FROM `movies`
 GROUP BY `decade`
 ORDER BY `count` DESC;
```

Keyword DESC tells to ordering function that we expect sorting in descending order (greater value first). Default for ORDER BY is ASC order (ascending; from smallest to largest).

---

### Upgrading query to return range

This is, of course, optional. Showing **decade** and **count** only sometimes may confuse us when trying to figure out what range of years that **count** belongs to.

Having range included in the result may be better solution. Our goal now is to upgrade this query to get something like this.

```
 +--------+-----------+-------+
 | decade | range     | count |
 +--------+-----------+-------+
 |    200 | 1990-1999 |  5401 |
 +--------+-----------+-------+
 |    201 | 2000-2009 |  5200 |
 +--------+-----------+-------+
 |    199 | 1980-1989 |  4720 |
 +--------+-----------+-------+
 |    196 | 1950-1959 |  3000 |
 +--------+-----------+-------+
 etc...
```

As we can see, years in range are all years with same first 3 digits. To get these digits we need formula

```
 FLOOR (`year`/10)
```

So formula for range is

```
 CONCAT (FLOOR(`year`/10), '0-', FLOOR(`year`/10), '9')
```

Function [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) returns string made by concatenation of comma-separated list of values.

Now it's good time to bring [variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) into the story. As you could figure out, formula FLOOR(year/10) was previously used with decade calculation. To keep our query simple we'll assign that formula to variable and use it where it's needed later. To assign some value to the variable in SQL we use

```
 @varname := value
```

(this is one way, not only)

If we modify SELECT clause this way

```
 SELECT
   (@d := FLOOR (`year`/10))+1 AS 'decade',
   COUNT(*) AS 'count'
 FROM...
```

we are able to use calculated value as **@d**.

Now we can write simpler version of range formula

```
 CONCAT (@d, '0-', @d, '9')
```

or even better

```
 CONCAT (@d*10, '-', @d*10+9)
```

For **@d=200** range is created by concatenation of values '200', '0-', '200' and '9' (1st formula) or by concatenation of '2000', '-' and '2009' (2nd formula). Both give a same result of '2000-2009'.

By upgrading our query with **range** column this way

```
 SELECT
   (@d := FLOOR (`year`/10))+1 AS 'decade',
   CONCAT (@d*10, '-', @d*10+9) AS 'range',
   COUNT(*) AS 'count'
 FROM...
```

we get a result like one from the sample above.

---

### Another optional upgrade

Today is year 2016 which belongs to decade 202. Range for decade 202 is 2010-2019. I'd like to show how to convert this range into '2010-today'. We can simple do that by checking if ending-year of the range is greater than current year and in that case replace it with text 'today',

Ending year of the range is created as

```
 @d*10+9
```

We basicaly have to check that value against the current year and decide what to do in which case. Current year we get using functions [YEAR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) and [CURDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate).

```
 YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Our task is to replace ending-year of range by text 'today' when ending-year id greater than current year, otherwise we keep original value. Using IF condition gets this job done.

```
 IF ((@r := @d*10+9) > YEAR(CURDATE()), 'today', @r)
```

Variable **@r** gets value of ending-year. When it's greater than current year [IF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) returns text 'today', if not, returns ending year (represented with **@r**).

All we need now is to modify our **range** formula in query. It becomes

```
 CONCAT (@d*10, '-', IF ((@r := @d*10+9) > YEAR(CURDATE()), 'today', @r)) AS 'range',
```

**Our FINAL QUERY now looks like this.**

```
 SELECT
   (@d := FLOOR (`year`/10))+1 AS 'decade',
   CONCAT (@d*10, '-', IF ((@r := @d*10+9) > YEAR(CURDATE()), 'today', @r)) AS 'range',
   COUNT(*) AS 'count'
 FROM `movies`
 GROUP BY `decade`
 ORDER BY `count` DESC;
```

Query above may return something like this:

### Result

```
 +--------+------------+-------+
 | decade |  range     | count |
 +--------+------------+-------+
 |    200 |  1990-1999 |  7560 |
 +--------+------------+-------+
 |    202 | 2010-today |  5921 | <-- modified range
 +--------+------------+-------+
 |    201 |  2000-2009 |  2456 |
 +--------+------------+-------+
 |    196 |  1950-1959 |   930 |
 +--------+------------+-------+
 etc...
```

Enjoy learning!

Comment: You shouldn't give the full answer, but clues which lead up to it. There are especially things in that query which are blatantly obvious that a new person to SQL would not use, and would likely just confuse the OP further.

Comment: The school project the poster asked about clearly isn't at the level of your SQL. It's also wrong to simply provide the answer to obvious homework questions, unless the homework assignment is *learn how to copy and paste the work of others*.

Comment: you purposely gave an overly complicated answer, which will lead to the OP research things that aren't related to the concepts involved nor help them outside of copy/pasting your answer anyhow. How is this helpful at all?

Comment: @KenWhite My answer answers the question and there's no SO rule that forbids answering **ANY** open question. Question itself is a problem (already voted to close it down before started to write this answer). So, I don't really see any problem.

Comment: @Rogue Assigning couple of vars and using few generic-functions from SQL cheat-sheet certainly aren't rocket-science. Or maybe everything more complex than `SELECT * FROM table` is forbidden for new learners. I understand that different parts of the world have different educational system but vars and functions are basic for any script language.